# Inconsistent behaviour of Next.js router.query

Tags: javascript, next.js, router, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am building a image search website using `nextjs`. In which there is route
`/search/photos/[slug]`, based on slug images are fetched from `unsplash api`.

```
const router = useRouter();
const {slug} = router.query;

useEffect(() => {
   if(router.isReady && slug) {
      fetchPhotos();
   }
}, [slug])


const fetchPhotos = () => {
    unsplash.search.getPhotos({
        query: slug,
        page: 1
        perPage,
    })
    .then((result) => {
        if (result.status === 200 && result.type === "success") {
          dispatch({ type: "SET_PHOTOS", payload: result.response.result })
        } 
        else {
          console.log(result.errors);
        }
     })
     .catch((info) => {
        console.log(info);
     });
};
```

When slug changes, `fetchPhotos` function sometime fetch data for previous value of slug. How to avoid this inconsistent behavior of `router.query.slug`, and get current route dynamic route `slug` value ?

Comment: Which version of NextJS is this? And is it appDir or pages?

Comment: @rguarascia.ts I am using nextjs 13 and pages.